# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

server.js where i've declared the permissions

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ui.router'])

.config(('$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('view',{
      url:'/',
      templateUrl:'js/components/view/view.html',
      controller:'viewCtrl'
    })

}))
```

view.js

```
.controller('viewCtrl',['$scope','$state','$http',function($scope,$state,$http)
{   

    $scope.pics=[];
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getNewPhoto').then(function(response){
        $scope.pics=response.data;
    },function(err)
    {
        console.error("There's an error"+err);
    })
}])
```

kindly help me out in this problem I've tried all possible solution but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [cors module](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) of express and you will be fine:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: do i need to add cors to pakage.json @lin

Comment: @AsadArshad great so the cors issue is fixed. Please create a new question including your next problem. I gonna pickup there. Please add your node part into the new question. A link to the new question would be nice :) Just post it as a comment please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300308/nothing-is-being-shown-while-theres-no-error-the-code-is-working-fine @lin

Answer (score 0):

You must add an important header. Add that line to server script:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
```

Comment: Are you sure that running your nodejs server on port 8080? May be tomcat or other server using this port

Comment: yes i'm running my server on 8080 and trying to access it from port 8100 but it's not working

Comment: This is really interesting. Can you access the service via Postman or directly from web browsrer?

Comment: now it's working using cors module but its not showing anything like i wanna call getPhotos nd it's not showing

Comment: @kodmanyaga only server.js is missing else other code is present here